# Adding one month to datetime64 with timedelta

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, timedelta

When I try this:

```
>>> a = numpy.datetime64('1995-12-31')
>>> b = a + pandas.Timedelta(1, unit='M')
>>> print(b)
```

I expect to see

```
1996-01-31
```

but instead I get

```
1996-01-30 10:29:06.
```

Any idea why? Many thanks.

Answer (score 11):

As already mentioned @hpaulj in his answer:

> There's an inherent ambiguity in adding a 'month' to a time, since months vary in length.

Moreover, as at version `0.25.0`, **Pandas** [dropped support](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew/v0.25.0.html#other-deprecations) for the use of the units `M` (months) and `Y` (years) in `Timedelta` functions.

But as stated in official pandas [guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects), you should use **Timedelta** for absolute time duration and **DateOffset** for relative time duration that respects calendar arithmetic, which is exactly what we need in your case:

> The basic **DateOffset** acts similar to `dateutil.relativedelta` ([relativedelta documentation](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html)) that shifts a date time by the corresponding calendar duration specified.

So, using your example:

```
In [7]: a = numpy.datetime64('1995-12-31')
      : b = pandas.Timestamp(a) + pandas.DateOffset(months=1)
      : b
Out[7]: Timestamp('1996-01-31 00:00:00')
```

NB: you could always use `to_numpy` method, if you need to convert `pandas.Timestamp` to `numpy.datetime64`.

Answer (score 1):

A time delta of one month is the length of a year divided by 12.

You need to examine your date and add the appropriate quantity of days.
Alternately, increment the month number (rolling over to the next year, if needed), and leave the day number unchanged.

Comment: _"A time delta of one month is the length of a year divided by 12."_ That seems to be the `pandas` (but not `numpy`) way of thinking.

Answer (score 1):

There's an inherent ambiguity in adding a 'month' to a time, since months vary in length.

Make a date:

```
In [247]: a = np.array('1995-12-31','datetime64[D]')                            
In [248]: a                                                                     
Out[248]: array('1995-12-31', dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

adding days to that works fine:

```
In [249]: a + np.array(31, 'timedelta64[D]')                                    
Out[249]: numpy.datetime64('1996-01-31')
```

Adding a month raises an error:

```
In [250]: a + np.array(1, 'timedelta64[M]')                                     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-250-a331f724d7e7> in <module>
----> 1 a + np.array(1, 'timedelta64[M]')

TypeError: Cannot get a common metadata divisor for NumPy datetime metadata [D] and [M] because they have incompatible nonlinear base time units
```

We could cast `a` as a month - then it works:

```
In [251]: a.astype('datetime64[M]')                                             
Out[251]: array('1995-12', dtype='datetime64[M]')
In [252]: a.astype('datetime64[M]') + np.array(1, 'timedelta64[M]')             
Out[252]: numpy.datetime64('1996-01')
```

Change the month in the corresponding `datetime` object may be cleanest way to work with this:

```
In [254]: b = a.item()                                                          
In [255]: b                                                                     
Out[255]: datetime.date(1995, 12, 31)
```

I haven't worked enough with `datetime` objects to make the change without looking at its docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `day` part to mimic the requirement.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
a = np.datetime64('1995-12-31')
b = a + pd.Timedelta(1, unit='M')
print(b.replace(day=pd.to_datetime(a).day))
```

Use `.date()` if you are only interested in date part

Answer (score 0):

A concise way of adding a month leaving the day unchanged if possible would be truncating to months, adding 1 and then readding what was truncated:

```
>>> a = np.datetime64('1995-12-31')                                                              
>>> am = a.astype('M8[M]')                                                    
>>> b = (am + 1) + (a - am)                                                        
>>> b                                                                                            
numpy.datetime64('1996-01-31')
```

Obviously, that does not work if the original day does not exist in the next month:

```
>>> a = np.datetime64('1995-01-31')
>>> am = a.astype('M8[M]')
>>> b = (am + 1) + (a - am)
>>> b
numpy.datetime64('1995-03-03')
```

But it is unclear what should be the answer in this case, anyway.

One possibility would be to max out at that month's last day:

```
>>> b = np.minimum((am + 1) + (a - am), (am + 2) - np.timedelta64(1, 'D'))
>>> b
numpy.datetime64('1995-02-28')
```