# Date Offset Pandas Field Based Off Another Field

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time

I have a data frame with a field `time` of timestamps with dates, and another column `period`. How can I add a number of days to `time` based on `period`?

Current Output:

```
time                 period
------------------------------
2020-04-28 10:00:00  1
2020-04-27 12:34:56  3
```

Expected Output

```
time
---------------
2020-04-29 10:00:00
2020-04-30 12:34:56
```

If I try `df['time'] = df['time'] + pd.DateOffset(df['period'])` I get an error `TypeError:`n`argument must be an integer, got <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>` because it is trying to pass the whole column into the function which expects an integer. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

Because days can be converted to timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) is possible use:

```
df['time'] = df['time'] + pd.to_timedelta(df['period'], unit='d')
print (df)
                 time  period
0 2020-04-29 10:00:00       1
1 2020-04-30 12:34:56       3
```

But if want add `month`s is necessary use:

```
df['time'] = df['time'] + df['period'].apply(lambda x: pd.DateOffset(months=x))
print (df)
                 time  period
0 2020-05-28 10:00:00       1
1 2020-07-27 12:34:56       3
```

If use `month timedelatas` is working with [`'default month'`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54794458/2901002), so precision is different:

```
df['time'] = df['time'] + pd.to_timedelta(df['period'], unit='M')
print (df)
                 time  period
0 2020-05-28 20:29:06       1
1 2020-07-27 20:02:14       3
```